# GitHub- iOS app with storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, version-control, github, storyboard

Does GitHub support Xcode's Storyboards?

If not, is there any version control system like Github that can deal with an app with storybards?

Comment: Yes, it supports storyboards. You can't "see" the storyboard graphically in GitHub, but it handles version control of the storyboards fine.

Comment: I have the same question: How can I collaborate with other people on a project, using Xcode's Storyboard? Not text based, but visually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a text based version control, storyboard is just an xml, so yes, Github supports it, but its bad practice since every little move will make a conflict

Comment: when you have 2 or more people touching the storyboard, you get a conflict

Comment: But the conflict will apear?